# Adb pull command from a device to pc

Tags: adb

If there is a space in the directory in the adb pull operation, say 
adb pull data/tombstones "c:/Program files/myApp"

is any other way to do it besides adding quotation mark on it "c://Program Files/myApp" to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the short name of the folder. for `program files` it is `progra~1`.
you can see short name with `dir /x`.

I've never tried it with ADB, but I think it should work.